# Deserializing jackson dynamic key value

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have a json structure similar to this

```
{
  "Byc-yes": { // < code
    "Updated": "week", // < period
    "Time": "12pm" // < time
  },
  "Uop-thp":{
    "Updated": "week",
    "Time": "12pm
  } ,
  ...
```

I want to deserialize it to a Java class

```
class Updating {
   private String code;
   private String period;
   private String time;
}
```

There any native JACKSON mappers to do this, or will I need to create my own custom deserializer for this?

Answer (score 1):

I will read it as `Map.class` and then iterate through keyset to extract values.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map map = objectMapper.readValue(s, Map.class);
    for (Object o : map.keySet()) {
        String key = (String) o;
        System.out.println(key);//prints Byc-yes for first
        Map<String, String> value = (Map<String, String>) map.get(key);
        System.out.println(value); //prints {Updated=week, Time=12pm} for first
        Updating updating = new Updating(key, value.get("Updated"), value.get("Time"));
        System.out.println(updating);
    }
```

Assuming `Updated` and `Time` are fixed keys.

Comment: got It. I forget to metion that i'm using unirest for the get request. This way still works?

Comment: above should work as long as you are getting a valid json